# Looking for a Ministry Law fanfiction where Hermione is forced to marry either Severus or Draco or lose her magic

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a story that I read on Fanfiction about 3 years ago and was complete with more that 10k words. It was after the Battle of Hogwarts, but I don't remember if it was tagged as such.

It was about a new law that forces people to marry or to lose their magic.
Hermione needed her magic to survive the scars from Bellatrix and went to look for the right person to marry. She was given a period to search for someone. The others too.

Draco suffered from the war and needs his magic too, as does Severus from his wounds from Nagini. Hermione talks to both of them and they get on friendly terms

Hermione has to choose between them, but choosing one would lead to magic loss of the other. She chooses to marry Severus. Severus doesn't think it would last and that she will change her mind. Draco gets more time to find a wife.

He had bought a new house before and was sleeping on an uncomfortable bed in another room, while he had placed a luxurious bed in the bedroom intended for his wife. Crookshanks is allowed in the house too.

When they have bound, they are given a time period to consummate the marriage in (48 or 72 hours maybe?). Severus is surprised when Hermione wishes to consummate the marriage as soon as possible. (Possible NSFW material so hidden in spoiler tags (not bad though)).

> Hermione startles when Severus screams out as he rubs his tip against her entrance and Hermione asks if he's hurt. He confesses that he hadn't done it in a while and when asked the details, the while is nearly two decades.

There was also a part about a bag with a blindfold 
(bought for Severus to use as she thought that she was too ugly to look at, Severus had the reversed thoughts). Lucius Malfoy walking in a sex shop (as he was the one who bought the stuff).

The cream Hermione uses is from the company Severus owns and offers her a better cream to put on the scarring.

After a while the law was resolved; Hermione read this first and threw away the newspaper and proceeded to make Severus a sandwich. She was called away for something and left a note.

Severus finds the newspaper and when he read it, he went into a panic mode. Then when he couldn't find Hermione he thought that she was gone and left Crooks with him to comfort him for a while and would come back for Crooks.

Hermione returns and they both talk to each other to workout their misunderstanding.

They live together afterwards. I don't remember anything else of the story and I hope that someone knows/remembers the name and/or writer of this story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it on Archiveofourown, but couldn't find it on Fanfiction anymore. The story was probably deleted some time ago.

Anyways the story was [Legislation](https://archiveofourown.org/works/3581625/chapters/7896243)  by orphan_account

Comment: Thank you for coming back to tell us what this was!

Comment: It was the right thing to do, since other people may have searched for the story too, to help me. (: